# Reversing every line in file using read() system call

Tags: c, linux, file

I am trying to get the read() system call to read my file line by line and reverse each line to stdout. My issue is getting read() to read my file line by line because normally it just reads the whole file. I want the LINE_BUFFER size to be the max size a line can be.

I tried implementing a function to try to do this but it seems to break the program and I am a little lost on how to approach this problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER 1024

int charCount(const char *name1);
ssize_t readline (char *buf, size_t a, int b, off_t *offset);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(argc ==2){
        charCount(argv[1]);
    }else{
        printf("Provide a file\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int charCount(const char *name1)
{
    char buffer[LINE_BUFFER];
    int fd;
    ssize_t len = 0;
    int nread;
    int i = 0;
    off_t offset = 0;
    if ((fd = open(name1, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error in opening file");
        return (-1);
    }

    int size = lseek(fd,-1, SEEK_END);

    while(size>=0)
    {
        while((len = readline(buffer,LINE_BUFFER,fd,&offset)) != -1){
            write(1,buffer,1);
            lseek(fd, -2,SEEK_CUR);
            size--;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    return(0);
}

ssize_t readline(char *buf, size_t a, int b, off_t *offset)
{
    int fd;

    ssize_t nchr =0;
    ssize_t idx =0;
    char *p = NULL;

    if ((nchr = lseek(fd, *offset, SEEK_SET)) != -1){
        nchr = read(fd,buf,a);
    }

    p = buf;
    while(idx<nchr && *p != '\n') p++,idx++;
    *p =0;

    if(idx == nchr) {
        *offset + nchr;
        return nchr < (ssize_t)a ? nchr : 0;
    }

    *offset += idx+1;
    return idx;
}
```

Comment: Read has no clue what a "line" is. `read()` read bytes. You can read your entire file into a buffer and then step through the resulting buffer operating on lines, but beyond that you would have to read 1-byte at a time and check each as you go.

Comment: @DavidCRankin so what you're saying is that it's not really possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you can do it one-byte-at-a-time (it's just an awkward way to handle lines). Far better to use `fgets()` to read one line-at-a-time into your buffer. (or read the whole file into a buffer and then operate on the whole thing at once)

Comment: Where do you set `fd` in `readline()`? it needs to be a function parameter.

Comment: Oh, you're passing `fd` to the `b` parameter. Why isn't that parameter called `fd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "normally it just reads the whole file".  `read` has a fairly low maximum size it will read, typically 4KiB or 8KiB.  In any case, I put together some code to reverse line of a file.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int xopen(const char *, int);
void * Realloc(void *, size_t);
void reverse(char *, char *);
char * findchr(char *, char *, char);

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        ssize_t rc;

        size_t siz = BUFSIZ;         /* size available to read into */
        char *buf = Realloc(NULL, BUFSIZ + siz); /* Pad the front */
        char *s = buf + BUFSIZ;      /* first char of a line */
        char *prev = s;              /* start of data from previous read */
        char *end = s;               /* one past last char read from input */
        int fd = argc > 1 ? xopen(argv[1], O_RDONLY) : STDIN_FILENO;

        while(( rc = read( fd, s, BUFSIZ )) > 0 ) {
                char *eol; /* A newline, or one past valid data */
                end = s + rc;

                if( (eol = findchr(s, end, '\n')) == end ) {
                        /* No newlines found in the last read.  Read more. */
                        if( end > buf + siz ) {
                                ptrdiff_t e_off = end - buf;
                                ptrdiff_t p_off = prev - buf;
                                siz += BUFSIZ;
                                buf = Realloc(buf, BUFSIZ + siz);
                                eol = end = buf + e_off;
                                prev = buf + p_off;
                        }
                        s = end;
                        assert( s <= buf + siz );
                        continue;
                }
                s = prev;
                do {
                        assert(*eol == '\n');
                        assert(eol < end);
                        reverse(s, eol-1);
                        s = eol + 1;
                        assert(s <= end);
                } while( (eol = findchr(s, end, '\n')) < end );
                assert(eol == end);
                assert(eol[-1] != '\n' || s == end);

                fwrite(prev, 1, s - prev, stdout);
                prev = buf + BUFSIZ - (end - s);
                memcpy(prev, s, end - s);
                eol = s = buf + BUFSIZ;
        }
        if(rc == -1) {
                perror(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if(prev < s) {
                reverse(prev, s-1);
                fwrite(prev, 1, s - prev, stdout);
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*
 * Find v between str and end.  If not found,
 * return end.  (This is basically strchr, but
 * doesn't care about nul.)
 */
char *
findchr(char *str, char *end, char v) {
        assert(str <= end);
        while( str < end && *str != v )
                str += 1;
        return str;
}

void
reverse(char *start, char *end)
{
        for( ; start < end; start++, end-- ) {
                char tmp = *end;
                *end = *start;
                *start = tmp;
        }
}


void *
Realloc( void *buf, size_t s )
{
        buf = realloc( buf, s );
        if( buf == NULL) { perror("realloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        return buf;
}

int
xopen(const char *path, int flag)
{
        int fd = open(path, flag);
        if( fd == -1 ) { perror(path); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
        return fd;
}
```

Comment: *`read` has a fairly low maximum size it will read, typically 4KiB or 8KiB*  The max `read` size on Linux [is a bit under 2 GB](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html): "On Linux, `read()` (and similar system calls) will transfer at most
       0x7ffff000 (2,147,479,552) bytes, returning the number of bytes
       actually transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit
       systems.)"  On Solaris, I've done 8+ GB `read()`/`write()` operations without issue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle.Wow...I guess I'm dated!  But to get 8+GB I suspect you're using large pages or some other parameter is tweaked.  When attempting to read large buffers on my personal laptop (macos), I'm bounded by 512000 from a regular file, and 30k-50k on a pipe.